# ttyAMA0 disabled but still shows one boot message

Tags: raspbian, uart

I'm trying to use the UART for my own purposes. I'm using Raspbian

I've edited cmdline.txt and inittab but I still get the one line message

> Uncompressing Linux... done, booting the kernel.

How do I stop this message from showing?

Solution: 
(@joan provided the answer in her link, but It needed tweaking to find the new offset, so  here's how to do find the offset)

You need to uncompress kernel.img which is found in the /boot directory (raspbian).  kernel.img contains a header and then gzipped data.  You first need to inspect the compressed kernel and find the offset to the compressed data (A gzip header in hex is &h1f8b0800).

```
od -A d -t x1 /boot/kernel.img | grep '1f 8b 08 00'
```

This should result in a line such as:

```
0017360 1f 8b 08 00 00 00 00 00 02 03 e4 fd 0b 7c 54 d5
```

or

```
0017360 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 1f 8b 08 00 00 00 00 00
```

In the first result above, the offset is 0017360, in the second the offset is 0017360+8=0017368

Take YOUR offset and replace the 17360 below

```
dd if=/boot/kernel.img skip=1 bs=17360 | gzip -d >/boot/kernel_uncompressed.img
```

If all went to plan, the kernel is now uncompressed, you now need to replace the compressed kernel with the uncompressed one (as root) over the kernel.

```
cd /boot
#Backup the compressed kernel
cp kernel.img kernel_compressed.img
#Replace the kernel
cp kernel_uncompressed.img kernel.img
#Reboot
reboot
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to boot the Pi from an uncompressed Linux image.

Have a look through http://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=44&t=33042&p=283774&hilit=uncompressing+kernel for one possibilty.

Answer (score 1):

Just adding information:

I've found 2 "kernel" files on Raspbian "Jessie":

1. `/boot/kernel.img`
2. `/boot/kernel7.img`

So I had to execute the procedure (well explained by John) with both files in order to "mute" the serial port at boot.

I"m not sure if everyone knows it, so just in case I thought better be clear.

Comment: The first one is used with BCM2835 models (A/B/+/0), the second, `kernel7`, is used with the BCM2836 Pi 2 B.  If you had to do this with both, it's probably because you are using a Pi 2 and doing it to the first one had no effect because it is not actually used.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is fixed in my project Nard SDK
http://www.arbetsmyra.dyndns.org/nard/advance.html#serialport